# apiKey and axios

Tags: javascript, api, axios

i'm trying to use an api of which i have both username and password, through this code I can get the authentication token

```
  axios.post(this.apiUrl,
            {
                username : 'xxx',
                password : 'yyy'
            },
  
  )
  .then((respond)=>{
    this.token = respond.data.token
    console.log(this.token)
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log('errore',error)
  })
```

since I need that token to access other routes in the same Api, I should reuse it in other requests, as in this case

```
  axios.post(this.apiUrl+(otherEndPoint),{body},
            {
              headers:{
                  "authorization":this.token
              }
            },
  
  )
  .then((respond)=>{
    r = respond.data.token
    console.log(r)
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log('errore',error)
  })
```

but it doesn't work, someone can help me

Comment: i think you need to add `Bearer` before the token like so : `Authorization: Bearer MyToken`

Comment: What doesn't work? Please describe the errors and format your question properly.

Comment: with postman if I use the token ,obtained from the first request ,inserting it in the value present in authorizations, I can get the data provided by the API...I have to be able to do the same thing with axios...provide the route of the second request with the token obtained from the first request to get the data

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are looking for Bearer Token or x-api-key.
Anyway, it should work like:

```
const token = "your token";
const res = await axios.post(URL, {data:"your_data"}, {
        headers: {
          // 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` 
          'x-api-key':`${token}`
        }
    })
```

In the code upper here, you have the 2 different auth methods, Bearer is commented.

Answer (score 2):

with no background on how your project is setup, the gist on how to do it is the following steps:

1. Create an axios instance (whether it be by using a CDN or importing axios from your project's installed packages)
2. Set the axios default headers.
3. Use the axios methods `get`, `post`, etc.

In code:

```
// Import axios module
import axios from 'axios';

// Set default header. e.g, X-API-KEY
axios.defaults.headers['X-API-KEY'] = 'some-api-key';

// Use axios as you would normally
axios.get('http://example.com/secure-endpoint')
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

For your context:

```
import axios from 'axios';

// ... somewhere in code
// Get api-key from server
const username = 'someUsername';
const password = 'somePassword';
axios.post('http://example.com/api/getKey', {
    username,
    password
}).then(res => {
    axios.defaults.headers['x-api-key'] = res.data.apiKey;
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
// ...

// ... somewhere else in code
axios.get('http://example.com/secure-endpoint')
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
// ...
```

These are just examples. Change according to your project's structure and needs.